# TinyMCE error "z is undefined "

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I want to add a custom button in the TinyMCE editor in the WordPress. I am trying following code, it works but it gives following error (please see the image below). I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem, I'll appreciate any help.

```
(function () {
    tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.myTest", {  
        createControl: function ( btn, e ) {
            if ( btn == "custom_button" ) {                 
                var a = this;               
                var btn = e.createSplitButton('custom_button', {
                    title: "Test",              
                });
                return btn;
            }           
            return null;
        },          

    });

    tinymce.PluginManager.add("myTest", tinymce.plugins.myTest);
})();
```

[image]

Comment: http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/issues/1382  - It say problem is TinyMCE 3.5.x. TinyMCE 3.4.9 is good. Which version u r using?

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ I'm using default library which comes with latest WP version. From the source i can see `majorVersion:"3",minorVersion:"5.8-wp2",releaseDate:"2013-02-11"`